# multiple tcp connections despite of http-alive

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, tcp, keep-alive

I'm not sure whether I understand **http-keep-alive** correctly, In my opinion, it should reuse the tcp connection, not building a new one. However, I found something really strange, it seems like it is hard to anticipate the behavior of **http keep-alive**.

---

Server: NodeJS & Express ^4.16.3
and I have used Wireshark to analyze the results

---

Situation 1:

- Server-side

```js
for(let i =1; i<11; i++){
  app.use('/' + i, (req, res) => {
    res.header('cache-control', 'no-store');
    res.send('i');
  });
}

server.keepAliveTimeout = 50000;
```

- Client side

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
      fetch('' + i).then(data => console.log(data));
    }
  }, 10000);
```

- result: tcp connection is reused(only one tcp connection), all fetch requests reuse the tcp connection established by index.html
  [image]

---

Situation 2:

- Client side codes are the same, only server side codes change here

```js
for(let i =1; i<11; i++){
  app.use('/' + i, (req, res) => {
    res.header('cache-control', 'no-store');
    // here I have added timeout!
    setTimeout(() => {
      res.send('i');
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

- result: 5 more tcp connection are established(in the picture only 4, because the screenshot is not complete), despite that I have set **server.keepAliveTimeout = 50000;**

[image]

---

So my question is, what does http keep alive really mean? why it behaves like this?
If it will not use the same tcp connection in situation 2, what is the meaning of keep alive??

appreciate for any thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HTTP Keep Alive should reuse your TCP connection with the server. The server append `Connection: keep-alive` Header with the response, So the client keeps the connection alive. So the client won't keep the connection alive till your server response.

So in your first scenario, The server replies with the header as soon as the request received. So the second response (actually may reuse, you got lucky since the server respond your request, before it sends the second one) reuses the TCP connection.

But in second scenario, server waits 2 seconds to send the response, So the client won't know it should be a keep alive connection till next 2 seconds. But all other requests need to be sent before that, so as default it will create a new connection for each HTTP Request.

This might be efficient if you need to continuously call HTTP interface, like req -> res -> req -> res, But also this might be inefficient if you want to get independent collection of data from the server.

Try this on client side if you have any doubts,

```
setTimeout(() => {
    fetch('' + i).then(data => console.log(data));

    setTimeout(function () {
        for (let i = 2; i < 11; i++) {
            fetch('' + i).then(data => console.log(data));
        }
    }, 5000)
}, 10000);
```

Comment: thank u for your post. It's actually not true, since for both situations, the request for `index.html` is always sent at the first place. And it returns immediately before I send the rest of fetch requests. So the client should already know that server has already set the keep alive

Comment: Hi I edited my answer if you like, please try this code and let me know what happens